# Error for indent or because of nesting if?

Tags: python

This should be a simple one! I would like to comparing timestamps in a text file formatted like so to see if they are older than 2 days:

```
20150217_00:47:32 - AAAAAA
20150217_00:47:32 - BBBBBB
20150217_00:47:32 - CCCCCC
```

I have some code that throws a syntax error on the 'if then > ... :' part of the code below, anyone see what's up? I wondered if it's because I can't nest the loops like this? (new to python but my indentation seems ok?). Also, am I trying to compare the date in the correct manner?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()

with open('notes.txt', 'r+') as notes:
        for line in notes:
            then = datetime.strptime('%Y%M%d_%H:%I:%S', line.strip()[:17]

            if then > datetime.timedelta(days=2):
                print 'Then was more than 2 days ago.'
            else:
                print 'Then was not more than 2 days ago.'
```

Error:

```
  File "notes.py", line 9
    if then > datetime.timedelta(days=2):
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: closing parenthesis is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Missing Closing bracket:

```
 then = datetime.strptime('%Y%M%d_%H:%I:%S', line.strip())[:17]
                                                         ^
```

Comment: Whether I add the bracket there or at the end of the line after [:17] it now throws another error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "notes.py", line 6, in <module>
    then = datetime.strptime('%Y%M%d_%H:%M:%S', line.strip()[:17])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '%Y%M%d_%H:%M:%S' does not match format '20150217_00:47:32'

Comment: you can ask this in another post, start a another thread for this issue

Comment: @joep1: The ValueError is because the function arguments are the wrong way around. Please see your previous question for further details.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
then = datetime.strptime('%Y%M%d_%H:%I:%S', line.strip()[:17]
```

should be probably:

```
 then = datetime.strptime('%Y%M%d_%H:%I:%S', line.strip())[:17]
```

check if that missing closing bracket was an error